# Applying system scale on GTK+ 2

Tags: gtk, gtk2

I have tried to run my GTK+ 2 application on a high DPI monitor and this leads to some layout issues because values that are passed to `gtk_widget_set_size_request()` are in pixels.

I can solve these problems by reading the `Xft.dpi` Xresource and multiplying all the pixel values I pass to `gtk_widget_set_size_request()` by it. Still, I'm wondering whether GTK+ 2 has an inhouse solution for this particular problem because my solution seems rather hackish.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about switching to Gtk3?

Comment: I'd first like to understand GTK+ 2's behaviour.

Comment: @Andreas: the remark is notheless valid. GTK+ 3 had some work on [HiDPI](https://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2013/06/28/hidpi-support-in-gnome/) and [fractionnal scaling](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2017/05/19/fractional-scaling-goes-east/), as well as Wayland support. Not GTK+ 2. So unless you're working on a legacy application not worth migrating, GTK+ 3 is the way to go.